# Opening a big file

Tags: windows-7, text-editors

I have a rather large log file on a Windows Server 2008 R2 computer.  It's a couple of gigabytes in size, but Notepad, Wordpad, Notepad++, etc can't open it.

Which program should I use to handle such a file?

Comment: Delete the log file. If it doesn't exist, it never happened!

Comment: assuming you only want to read, not to edit, list.exe in the Windows 2003 resource kit should do the trick.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657

Answer (score 2):

**It would have to be a 64-bit program to handle a file larger than 2 GB.** This actually not a *technical* limitation but an *implementation* issue since most programs simply try to load an entire file in memory.

Whenever I encountered that issue on Windows, I found that **MS Visual Studio 2010 (64-bits) works**, at least for a few gigs. I realize if you do not have that software already it is an expensive buy just to open a file but you may be able to at least get a trial version.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.  How big do you mean by "a few gigs?"

Comment: There is no VS 2010 x64. There is only a 32 bit version of Vs 2010. Did you mean 32 bit VS 2010 on x64 OS?

Comment: Reading and writing files with sizes above 2GigaBytes **is** possible with the free VC10 (express edition) in a fully 32bit environment (OS **and** compiler). Although allocating chunks of that size will most probably not work, this will not keep a well designed program from modifing (editing) such big files. So there is **no** need to go for any 64bit tools to handle this big-file-issue.

Comment: @Ganesh - I'll double-check that. I thought the one on my work computer was 64-bits, maybe it as both binaries. At least it is running under a 64-bit system.

Comment: **2** gigabytes?  That's it?

Answer (score 2):

Vim is a great one. Others include 010 Editor, or so I've heard, and SlickEdit. Though slick edit is really geared to coding, it should handle large text files ok.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to handle my text file.  How big of a file can it handle?

Comment: Ive seen it chew up a 5GB file before, bizarre. Are you getting a size limitation related error, or maybe there is some other file corruption or problem at work here.

Comment: I think it's a size limitation.  Although, if it can handle 5 GB, I'm sure it could handle my file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't open it in an editor.  Try using `findstr` on it to search for the lines you are interested in.  That way you don't have to load the whole file into memory at once.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Answer (score 1):

I think you have ruled out most editors.

Why not just create a small console utility (x64 prefered) (say in C#) which will read all the text and break it down into smaller managable files which can be then read using notepad++?

Comment: I don't know if a x64 application would work.  How much memory can they use?

Comment: @HughJass Practically a x64 application can use OS max virtual memory. So sky is the limit.